# Sending data between components in Angular4

Tags: angular, service, eventemitter

Is there any alternative for @Input() and @Output() for sending data between components in angular?

Comment: Do you mean a different syntax or a whole different way of data exchange?

Comment: Yes, you can use a service, and, in that service you can have observables / event emitters, so, in that components you can subscribe to service events.

Comment: What kind of alternative? For what purpose?

Answer (score 4):

There is an entire section in the official docs dedicated to this topic. [Check it out](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

The gist of it:

- `@Input()` and `@Output()`
- `@ViewChild()` and template variables.
- via a service (with `Subject` and `Observables`)